# Oracle error "SQL command not properly ended" (ORA-00933) for Java prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, prepared-statement

I'm getting ORA-00933 when creating the following prepared statement for Oracle 10g (10.2.0.1.0) using JDBC:

```
conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO fx_tv_date (id, mp, doc_id, effective, actual, stale, val) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

That line is throwing the following exception...

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:801)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1039)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:841)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1134)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1274)
  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:205)
  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:205)
```

This works fine in MySQL & MS SQL Server so I guess it's a syntax difference with Oracle, but having searched online I can't seem to see the cause. For clarity here's the prepared statement on its own:

```
INSERT INTO fx_tv_date (id, mp, doc_id, effective, actual, stale, val) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. The statement is correct and works fine.

Comment: Interesting, from reading the error text I assumed this must be a syntactic issue, I'll go check...

Comment: Are you positive that's the line that's throwing the exception?  `prepareStatement` appears nowhere in the stack trace that you've shown.  I wouldn't expect `prepareStatement` to result in a call to  `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

That method to use is excuteUpdate, not executeQuery to execute DML.